# How to draw the function $f(x)=(x^2(e^x-1))^{\frac{1}{5}}$?

Tags: graphing-functions

I would like to draw the following function:  $f(x)=(x^2(e^x-1))^{\frac{1}{5}}$

I can draw the function $x^\frac{1}{5}$ pretty easily, but now I'm struggling to represent the function as a whole.

Comment: I would compute the first derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Write your $$f(x)$$ in the form $$f(x)=x^{2/5}(e^x-1)^{1/5}$$